# How to safely try out a Fork bomb

Tags: bash

I've been playing around with Unix for a while and I just found out the lovely piece of code that everybody calls a fork bomb: `:(){ :|:& };:`.  I wanna try it, but I know that it'll lag my computer like insane, so I was just wondering if anybody could give me some steps so that my computer doesn't lag when I run the command.  Thanks for the help :D

Comment: What are you expecting to see when you try it? Anyway, I'm not sure that this classifies as an on-topic question here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Warning: you are much better off attempting this in a virtual machine. The following is my experience, but I can't guarantee your results will be similar.**

---

You can use `ulimit -u` to cap the number of processes the current user is allowed. Note the limit will *include* processes already running or started elsewhere, so you'll need to make it fairly large. (100 was too small for me, but 500 allowed me to start the fork bomb.) **The limit also applies to your system as a whole, so you may need to reboot afterwards.** (On Mac OS X, I had exited out of any shells, then was unable to start any more programs, including a shell where I might remove the limit.)

Caveat emptor: the limit of 500 seemed to crash my shell, but a limit of 200 seemed to get my shell in an endless loop of trying to start new processes without succeeding.

```
$ ulimit -u 500
$ :(){ :|:& };:
[kaboom]
```

Answer (score 1):

Without any warranty. With linux you can try to edit your  /etc/security/limits.conf
You can add some thing like

```
 youruser hard nproc 80
```

In this case your user can only run 80 processes. This should stop the forkbomb before some thing happens. But it also effects other processes.

Best you try it within a virtual machine or a system which isn't important.

Answer (score 1):

An elaboration of slowjack's answer (mainly because I can't comment):

Create or find an empty user that's doing nothing, limit their processes to something, then run the fork bomb.

Running things as root, or a user with lots of privileges (especially known destructive things) is a bad idea. Linux systems don't come with seatbelts and helmets, they can easily destroy themselves.